# Can you have in-app purchase in a free app?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am making a game for windows 8 and I am going to have ads in it. I want to offer to remove ads as an in-app purchase but according to the microsoft guides the app has to have been sold to be able to handle in-app purchases. Are there any ways to allow in-app purchases without selling the app? I want it to be free, not sold or trialed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this. I dont know where you've seen you cant. I do this in two of my apps (Peregrine and "Map Wallpaper")

Comment: I read the following article on msdn on how to enable in-app purchases: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694067.aspx, it says: "To see how this experience looks to the customer, see The in-app purchase experience for a customer. Note that a customer can only make an in-app purchase if they've purchased a full version of your app.". Perhaps they mix purchased with just downloading then?

Comment: Many free apps offer in-app purchases, as this is a common scenario. The line you're referring to is simply describing the design of that particular example; it is not describing a platform requirement. I can see how it can be misinterpreted--the example is just saying that the trial/free version of the app chooses to not enable additional in-app purchases. You can choose otherwise.

Comment: Aha, thank you very much Kraig Brockschmidt - MSFT. I'll accept this as an answer then.

Comment: Thanks for your response and for clarifying. I had the same impression that this scenario was not supported by only reading the MSDN documentation.